# Select entries which doesn't have specified key

Tags: mongodb, properties, sql-drop, nosql

Assume, that I have bunch of entries in a document:

`db.document`

and some of them doesn't have some key, let's say name. So we have two types of entries - with and without name.

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("4dea81a8bd2bb0323800002d"), "fetched_at" : ISODate("2013-08-02T17:41:30Z"),    "keyword" : "110770", "name" : "SOME NAME" }`

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("4dea81a8bd2bb0323800002a"), "fetched_at" : ISODate("2013-08-02T17:44:17Z"),    "keyword" : "125176" }`

I want to remove all entries without `name` property, because it makes my database incosistent. How can I do that? I tried with `null` and `undefined` but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's possible using [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/#op._S_exists):

```
db.document.remove( { name : { $exists : false } } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.document.remove( { name : null } )
```

should work too. Example:

```
> db.document.insert({"fetched_at" : ISODate("2013-08-02T17:41:30Z"), "keyword" : "110770", "name" : "SOME NAME"})
> db.document.insert({"fetched_at" : ISODate("2013-08-02T17:44:17Z"), "keyword" : "125176" })
> db.document.insert({"fetched_at" : ISODate("2013-08-02T17:44:17Z"), "keyword" : "125176" })
> db.document.find().size()
3
> db.document.remove({name:null})
> db.document.find().size()
1
> db.document.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("520eac7e5d0ee1aa8515a550"),
    "fetched_at" : ISODate("2013-08-02T17:41:30Z"),
    "keyword" : "110770",
    "name" : "SOME NAME"
}
```